# Android Inbox SMS receiving in different parts

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I am developing an android app which gets the SMS using broadcast receiver when its comes. Here is the code:

`if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs;
            if (bundle != null) {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        String address = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String body = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
}`

Problem is that few messages I receive comes in two or three parts. I don't know how to join these parts of messages. How can I detect that the first part of message needed to be combined with the next part message.

First Part: `Your airtel mobile ********** online recharge txn ID ************ o`

Second Part: `f Rs *** has been initiated. Please keep the txn id for future refe`

Third Part: `rence.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add message body(parts).
change this

```
          String body = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
```

to

```
          String body += msgs[i].getMessageBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your loop try this out, you should be fine

```
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    String str = "";

    if (bundle != null) {
        // Retrieve the SMS Messages received
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        // For every SMS message received
        for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            // Convert Object array
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            // Sender's phone number
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
            // Fetch the text message
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();              
            str += "\n";
        }

        // Display the entire SMS Message
        Log.d(TAG, str);
    }
```